# Scala string interpolation. `raw` prefix in regex

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

The `raw` prefix can be used to tell to the compiler not to escape any characters in string. But why I get compilation error when I try to do like this?

```
raw"\d".r  // not escaped slash
```

Comment: I don't get any compilation errors on 2.10.2

Comment: String interpolation was introduced in scala 2.10 http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Scala are you using? Works fine in 2.10.0:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_37).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> raw"\d".r
res0: scala.util.matching.Regex = \d
```